# Why is my stack trace missing steps?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

My logged stack trace seems to be missing a step.

```
private void StartLoadingResources(DataService separateDataService)
{
    ...
    batchResource.Resources.Add(key, new List<string>());
    // batchResource.Resources is the Dictionary object involved
    ...
}
```

Why has the stack trace gone straight from `StartLoadingResources` to `Insert` (missing the `Add` step)?

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at MyApp.Importer.StartLoadingResources(DataService separateDataService) in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Importer.cs:line 313
   at MyApp.Importer.<Execute>b__5() in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Importer.cs:line 142
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at MyApp.Importer.Execute() in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Importer.cs:line 157
   at MyApp.Program.Execute() in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Program.cs:line 252
   at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Program.cs:line 47
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at MyApp.Importer.StartLoadingResources(DataService separateDataService) in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Importer.cs:line 313
   at MyApp.Importer.<Execute>b__5() in ****\MyApp\MyApp\Importer.cs:line 142
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

The code is compiled as Debug, with "Optimize code" in Build options left unchecked.

Comment: Make sure 'Suppress JIT optimization on module load' is checked in the Debugging options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Add](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,191) method on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` simply calls `Insert`, given that it's a 1 line method, the compiler has simply inlined that method call as it is so trivial even without optimizations enabled.